# Formula For Rate of Increase of Money

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If person 1 receives 1,000,000 dollars and wants to both keep 1,000,000 dollars and give 1,000,000 dollars to person 2 within 1 year, then the money must be doubled in 1 year. If person 1 wants to still have 1,000,000 dollars after 2 years and give 1,000,000 dollars each to persons 2,3,4, and 5 within the 2 years, at what rate must the money be increased for this to be possible? How would this be set up as a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be initial amount, $r$ be rate of interest in $\%$, $y$ be number of years and $n$ be number of people other than person 1 (as per your question). Also, assuming it's simple interest.

Interest $I = \dfrac{Ary}{100}$

However, $I = nA$

Therefore, $nA = \dfrac{Ary}{100} \implies r = \dfrac{100n}{y}$. So, it is independent of initial amount.

So, in your example, there are $4$ people ($n = 4)$ and $y =2$.

Therefore, $r = \dfrac{100\times4}{2} = 200\%$

Comment: The rate of interest should be 100%, because $1,000,000\cdot (1+r)^2=4,000,000 \Rightarrow r=100\%$

Comment: @calculus I already wrote I'm assuming simple interest.